# ideal source and ideal current in series

Tags: circuit-analysis

[image]

I am trying to find Voltage between current source.
I have done  -6 + 4000 * 0.002 - Vi = 0 ,  Vi= 2 V

But the answer is -2 V meaning it should be -6 + 8 + Vi = 0, Vi = -2V

What is the sign convention of an ideal current source suppose to be for KVL, as i thought it was

(-) --> (+)

Comment: I would assume that it is measured in the direction of the arrow, which is what you have done.  but this picture is using  non-standard symbols for everything (even the resistor has non-standard markings)

Comment: The sign depends on your assumption regarding current source polarity. You considered (-) -> (+) from top to bottom, but the answer assumes (+) -> (-). Both answers are correct. From power perspective, P_V = 6V * 2mA = 12 mW (production), P_R = (2mA)^2*4kΩ = 16 mW (consumtion) and P_I = 2V * 2mA = 4 mW (production).

Answer (score 1):

That diagram is a littler weird as @Jasen mentioned. However, you did seem to go backwards with the current source compared to how all EE and physics classes I've been in have taught it. Starting with ground (I'll assume to be between voltage source and current source) and going clockwise, we increase by 6V, drop by 4k*2m = 8 V (Ohm's law), and then drops by Vi volts. By Kirchhoff's Voltage law, we should be back at ground. Therefore, 6 - 8 - Vi = 0, so Vi = -2V